# Bad request on backend when it came from angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a user verification email. The email body consist of my angular 2 route `localhost:4200/verify/{userId}`. When the user clicks the link, it will get to my angular 2 route and then I will split the URL to get the userId and pass it into my service.

Please take a look at my verify.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    var str = this._router.url;
    var userId = str.split('/');
    this._verifyService.verifyUser(userId[2])
        .subscribe((user) => console.log(user),
        (err) => console.log(err));
}
```

This is the service where it passes the value.

```
export class VerifyService{
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    verifyUser(userId){
        var headers = new Headers();
        console.log(userId);
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/verify', userId, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(this._handlerError)
    }

    _handlerError(err: any){
        console.log(err);
        // throw err;
        return Observable.throw(err);
    }
}
```

Then this is the back end that handles the updating of user to be verified.

```
  userRouter.route('/verify')
    .post(function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      var userId = req.body.userId;
      console.log(userId);
      users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { $set: { verified: true } }, { new: true })
        .exec(function (err, user) {
          res.json(user);
        });
    });
```

When the request is coming from **Postman**, it works. It updates user record and change it to verified but when I use it using angular2 it returns a bad request **400**. Why? Can anyone explain?

**NOTE**: I have other request like this and it works. The only difference is the approach which is it came from an email and I click the link. I don't know if this information helps but it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by converting the string URL to an object. I think the problem with the header which is `appplication/json` the value that it passes is a string. Now I am passing the value as an object and it does the trick!